# What is eclipse doing after it builds my c++ code?

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am using Juno (downloaded today).  I setup a new project with perhaps 10,000 c++ files.  I also setup a custom build command that does an ssh out to a remote machine to build the code.  (The code is on a drive shared by both machines.)  When I build, the console output shows the build command, and it runs and completes pretty quickly.  However, after the ssh command is done, it takes perhaps 2-5 minutes before the "Build Project" dialog goes away.  In the details section it just says "Building Project...", and the progress bar does not move beyond 25%.  The back and forth animation in the lower right of eclipse is moving back and forth.

Does anyone know what Eclipse is actually doing during this time?

Does anyone know how to make it stop whatever it is doing?